# Making a batch request to Facebook API from a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: facebook, api, spreadsheet

I am using a Google Spreadsheet to make HTTP requests to the Facebook API, which is fine for pulling one object at a time into the spreadsheet.

But I want to pull an array of posts from a Facebook page into the Google Spreadsheet. I tried the following function:

```
function FBposts(pagename) {
  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://graph.facebook.com/"+pagename+"/posts");
  var object = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());
  return object;
}
```

But this returns an error 400. I think it's because it makes a batch request that requires an access token.

How can I pass an access token to Facebook from a Google Spreadsheet function?

I have read the Facebook API documentation on Authentication and on Batch Requests, but cannot see how the examples could be adapted to Google Spreadsheets. I have tried searching on this question but found no results.

Thanks for your time.